# Typo3 Extbase plugin Schelduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, typo3, extbase

Is there any tutorial or example how to call extbase action from Schelduler?
I found something about CommandControler, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps (although in German)

http://www.derhansen.de/2012/06/seit-extbase-4.html

Answer (score 0):

.Make sure that in your **LocalConfiguration.php** are right credentials to DB.
It is important if you want to run script with CLI. Like: sudo php `./typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler`

Otherways even if you put "**echo**" or "**var_dump**" in YourCommandController it will be not ouputed. The script stops by trying to get user info from DB.